# Do HTML parser and CSS parser work in parallel?

Tags: browser, rendering, html-parsing

When it comes to rendering a page, we know there is an HTML parser that parses HTML and a CSS parser that parses CSS.

So, do they work in parallel? I think the HTML parser and CSS parser belong to the GUI rendering thread, so they can only work serially. But I'm not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are in parallel. but not part of the GUI thread